# Steps to configure iPod shuffle in Fedora 19

Tags: fedora, configuration, ipod

I am using Fedora 19 GNOME version.

After I plugin my iPod to the USB, it is not listed in my filesystem.

The output of the `lsusb` command is:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 090c:237c Silicon Motion, Inc. - Taiwan (formerly Feiya Technology Corp.) 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05ac:1303 Apple, Inc. iPod Shuffle 4.Gen
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

the output of `fdisk -l` is:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes Disk label type: gpt


#         Start          End    Size  Type            Name  1         2048       411647    200M  EFI System      EFI System Partition  2     411648      1435647    500M  Microsoft basic   3      1435648    976773119  465.1G  Linux LVM       

Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-root: 53.7 GB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-swap: 4177 MB, 4177526784 bytes, 8159232 sectors Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-home: 441.5 GB, 441505021952 bytes, 862314496 sectors Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sdb: 2018 MB, 2018496512 bytes, 492797 sectors Units = sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes Disk label type: dos Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
```

So, `sdb` is my iPod.

The output of `mount -t hfsplus /dev/sdb /media/ipod/` is:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

Then I tried checking the logfile `dmesg | tail -30`. The output was:

```
[254134.677536] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage 
[254135.680855] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Apple    iPod   2.70 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2 
[254135.681654] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0 
[254135.682437] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 492797 4096-byte logical blocks: (2.01 GB/1.87 GiB)
[254135.683072] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off 
[254135.683077] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 6e 00 00 08 
[254135.683678] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Incomplete mode parameter data 
[254135.683682] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through 
[254165.979596] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci 
[254197.054873] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[254228.066118] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci 
[254259.205331] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci 
[254259.294409] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 492797 4096-byte logical blocks: (2.01 GB/1.87 GiB) 
[254259.295670] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Incomplete mode parameter data 
[254259.295674] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through 
[254290.152447] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci 
[254321.227721] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci 
[254352.238989] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci 
[254383.250192] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci 
[254383.337942]  sdb: 
[254383.339261] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 492797 4096-byte logical blocks: (2.01 GB/1.87 GiB) 
[254383.340499] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Incomplete mode parameter data 
[254383.340503] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through 
[254414.261274] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci 
[254445.400659] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci 
[254476.411854] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci 
[254507.423071] usb 1-1.2: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci 
[254507.509440] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk 
[254606.269395] hfsplus: unable to find HFS+ superblock 
[254921.669943] hfsplus: unable to find HFS+ superblock
```

I also have gtpod and banshee installed. How do I get the iPod configured and running?

Comment: Please edit your question and copy-paste the output of `fdisk -l` and `dmesg`, this time without rewrapping the lines. Use code formatting (`Ctrl+K` or the `{}` button), not blockquote formatting which destroys the line breaks and makes the information unreadable.

Comment: The line breaks are still missing. You can't edit from what you have: using the blockquote formatting tool removed the line breaks that are necessary to make sense of this mess.